# Capture camera view and onverlay in an image

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay

I open the camera view and place an image as an overlay.
I then want to save both the overlay and the camera view's image as one image.
Previously I achieved this using UIGetScreenImage().
Now that Apple forbid this what are my options ?
takePicture will only capture the camera data but the the overlay.
Merging the overlay with the image from takePicture is a bit slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really will have to merge them, and it shouldn't take more than a second or two.  Something like(untested, but should give an idea):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myCapturedImage.size);
[myCapturedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero]; //You might need to use drawInRect
[overlayImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this is the very close to the way I ended up doing it.

Comment: One thing I found is that it was didFinishSavingWithError that was taking ages to be called. I'm looking into this. It also appears to lock the UI until it's called. I would have thought the image saving would have been done on a separate thread?

Comment: You can run it on a separate thread using [NSThread performBlockInBackground:^{}.  Make sure that nothing used by the block is released until the block completes!