# Issue on merging the overlay image with capture image ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing the camera app in which I put the one overlay image, As I captured the Image. I am doing the processing to combine the Image using the Following code but the position of the logo is not proper.

```
- (UIImage*)addOverlayToBaseImage:(UIImage*)baseImage {
     UIImage *newImage = [self CombineImage:baseImage];
     return newImage;
}

-(UIImage *)CombineImage :(UIImage*)myCapturedImage{ 

  CGSize finalSize = [myCapturedImage size];
  CGSize overlaySize = [overlayGraphic size];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(finalSize);

  [myCapturedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,finalSize.width,finalSize.height)];

  CGFloat xScaleFactor = finalSize.width / 320;
  CGFloat yScaleFactor = finalSize.height / 480;

  [overlayGraphic drawInRect:CGRectMake(30 * xScaleFactor, 100 * yScaleFactor, overlaySize.width * xScaleFactor, overlaySize.height * yScaleFactor)]; 

  UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return combinedImage;
 }
```

I take the reference from this url [http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1681] and use that onr [Capture camera view and onverlay in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882587/capture-camera-view-and-onverlay-in-an-image)

Please guide me if any mistake on my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
- (UIImage*)addOverlayToBaseImage:(UIImage*)baseImage{

UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];    
CGPoint topCorner = CGPointMake(0, 0);
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);   
CGRect scaledRect = CGRectZero;

CGFloat scaledX = 480 * baseImage.size.width / baseImage.size.height;
CGFloat offsetX = (scaledX - 320) / -2;

scaledRect.origin = CGPointMake(offsetX, 0.0);
scaledRect.size.width  = scaledX;
scaledRect.size.height = 480;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);    
[baseImage drawInRect:scaledRect];  
[overlayImage drawAtPoint:topCorner];   
UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

return result;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace this line:

```
 [overlayGraphic drawInRect:CGRectMake(30 * xScaleFactor, 100 * yScaleFactor,
 overlaySize.width * xScaleFactor, overlaySize.height * yScaleFactor)];
```

with this line

```
[overlayGraphic drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, finalSize.width, finalSize.Height)];
```