# Couldn't capture overlay image

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have 3 images. I load one by one to camera overlay image. Then i need to take snapshot. But when i click button it take snapshot of particular image. When i put imageName.png in captureStillImageWithOverlay it take snapshot of that image only, it won't taking other images when present in overlay

Button click code:

```
- (void)ButtonPressed {

  [[self captureManager] captureStillImageWithOverlay:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];

  }
```

Load images:

```
-(void)loadNextPage:(int)index
{


    int countFlag=0;
    for(int i=index*4;i<(index+1)*4;i++)
    {
        UIButton *imageView=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320*index)+countFlag*80+ 2, 5, 75, 75)];
        imageView.tag=i+1;
        [imageView addTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
        [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        switch ((i+1)%5) {
            case 0:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                break;

            case 1:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                break;

            case 2:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;

}

        [myScrollView addSubview:imageView];



        [imageView release];
        countFlag++;
    }
}
```

Capture overlay image:

```
- (void)captureStillImageWithOverlay:(UIImage*)overlay
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [[self stillImageOutput] connections]) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", [self stillImageOutput]);


 [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                             CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
                                                             if (exifAttachments) {
                                                                 NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
                                                             } else {
                                                                 NSLog(@"no attachments");
                                                             }

                                                             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                                                             UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                                                             CGSize imageSize = [image size];
                                                             CGSize overlaySize = [overlay size];

                                                             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

                                                             [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];

                                                             CGFloat xScaleFactor = imageSize.width / 320;
                                                             CGFloat yScaleFactor = imageSize.height / 480;

                                                             [overlay drawInRect:CGRectMake(30 * xScaleFactor, 100 * yScaleFactor, overlaySize.width * xScaleFactor, overlaySize.height * yScaleFactor)]; // rect used in AROverlayViewController was (30,100,260,200)

                                                             UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                                                             [self setStillImage:combinedImage];

                                                             UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

                                                             [image release];
                                                             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];

                                                     }];


}
```

I take the reference from this url [[http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1681]](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1681)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An overlay is just for presentation in the camera picker.

You also need to combine these images in your final UIImage (JPEG or TIFF or whatever) you save to disk.

[Other people have had (and have solved) this same problem as you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262495/issue-on-merging-the-overlay-image-with-capture-image-ios).

EDIT, here is some code that *may* help you out:

```
- (void)captureStillImageWithOverlay:(NSArray *) arrayOfImageFiles
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [[self stillImageOutput] connections]) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", [self stillImageOutput]);

 [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                             CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
                                                             if (exifAttachments) {
                                                                 NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
                                                             } else {
                                                                 NSLog(@"no attachments");
                                                             }

                                                             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                                                             UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                                                             CGSize imageSize = [image size];

                                                             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

                                                             [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];

                                                             CGFloat xScaleFactor = imageSize.width / 320;
                                                             CGFloat yScaleFactor = imageSize.height / 480;

                                                             for(NSString * imageFileName in arrayOfImageFiles)
                                                             {
                                                                 // images named @"img1" or @"img1.png" should work
                                                                 UIImage * overlay = [UIImage imageNamed: imageFileName];
                                                                 if(overlay)
                                                                 {
                                                                     CGSize overlaySize = [overlay size];

                                                                     [overlay drawInRect:CGRectMake(30 * xScaleFactor, 100 * yScaleFactor, overlaySize.width * xScaleFactor, overlaySize.height * yScaleFactor)]; // rect used in AROverlayViewController was (30,100,260,200)
                                                                 } else {
                                                                     NSLog( @"could not find an image named %@", imageFileName);
                                                                 }
                                                             }

                                                             UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                                                             [self setStillImage:combinedImage];

                                                             UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

                                                             [image release];
                                                             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];

                                                     }];


}
```

Comment: The problem is it capture only one image what i used in this line  [[self captureManager] captureStillImageWithOverlay:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];

Comment: well what I see in your code is that you are calling "`[[self captureManager] captureStillImageWithOverlay:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];`" and inside that method it's combining "`img2.png`" with whatever is coming in via "`videoConnection`".  Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Now i want capture img1, img3 when presenting in camera overlay...But when i use this line [[self captureManager] captureStillImageWithOverlay:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]]; it capture img2 only.

Comment: hmmmm... perhaps if you change the parameter to "`img1.png`" or "`img3.png`", you might get img1 or img3 in there, yes?

Comment: Im a beginner to iOS. Help me

Comment: welp, if you see how you can pass in one single image as a parameter, why not send in an array of UIImages and then add each member of the array (which would be a `UIImage`) the same way the single image gets combined with the video input?

Comment: You say like NSArray *images=[[NSArray arrayWithobjects:[@"img1",@"img2",@"img3",nil];   Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you are on the right track.  See what you can do with an array of PNG files.

Comment: But how can i use code to inside  [[self captureManager] captureStillImageWithOverlay:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];

Comment: i added like this  [self captureStillImageWithOverlay:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img1.png",@"img2.png",@"img3.png", nil]];  But it won't give any output overlay image

Comment: I was trying to *gently guide you* to your own answer but it sounds like you need more hand holding. I've edited my answer to show how to do this with an array. I sincerely hope this helps you out.

Comment: If i add more images like img4,img5. Then i can use this line UIImage * overlay = [UIImage imageNamed: imageFileName]; Is imageFileName take imageName from project bundle path?

Comment: ScrollView images are displaying only few seconds in device, then it goes off. why?

Comment: when i capture image i got error. [UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d53b6b0
2013-04-02 11:27:18.748 ARimage[1166:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d53b6b0'

Comment: I used array in button click for capture image:           - (void)ButtonPressed {

[self captureStillImageWithOverlay:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"], nil]];

  }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27384/discussion-between-ram-and-michael-dautermann)